# Please Help me solve as detailed as possible. I can't remember.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$X + (12 \text{% of } X ) = 3000$

I cant remember how to solve this. What do you call this type of equation and how do you solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The given equation is $$x+ \frac{12x}{100}=3000.$$ Can you solve it now.

The given equation states that there exists an $x$, such that $x$ added to $12$ percent of itself gives $3000$, find $x$, which can be put together to solve as above.

Comment: Yes absolutely. I Get it now. 12% is the same as 12/100. Which makes it much easier. Thanks! I could solve it like that!

Comment: Sweet and short but effective so +1. Thanks for saying so. I like my avatar, Shobhit. :-)

Comment: @BabakS. you are welcome.